# while loop not iterating properly to remove table rows

Tags: javascript

Just trying to remove a table but loop is not removing all rows. 
I have used alert to be sure it's the right element by id.
It does remove some rows but not all, just chunks.
console reports: DOM Exception 1,DOM Exception 8

```
function removeThis(unsetElement)
{ unsetElement.parentNode.removeChild(unsetElement); }
```

Comment: I have edited the original code with just removing the table as suggested. YAY ME! Thx for all the help guys.

Comment: You should at least not remove the original code in your question, otherwise the answers don't make sense anymore for other readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you remove rows, their indices change; you need to do the loop from the top, i.e.

```
i=rowCounter-1;
while(i>=0){unsetTable.deleteRow(i);i--;}
```

Yet the better idea is just to purge the whole table; rows will be garbage-collected.

Comment: ok. i have updated the script with your suggestion and no rows are removed and a DOM Exception 1 was reported in the console.

Comment: if i could just remove the table i would but that was also not working and i thought i had to remove the child nodes or something. i really just wish they made a frontend php.

Comment: @Richard Sorry, should work now. What is wrong with removing the whole table?

Comment: nothing wrong with it, but trying to function removeTable()
{
document.getElementById('article').removeChild('editing');
} returns the same Exception 8 error. I have about 3 weeks of javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be to use the special `-1` index, which deletes the last row.

```
var i = thisTrAry.length;

while(i--) {
    unsetTable.deleteRow(-1);
}
```

But if you remove the whole table anyway (in your last line) then there is no need to remove the rows first.